# RichTextBox bold monospace font?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox control on one of my forms, and I use a monospace font as it contains formatted text. I'm trying to implement a search functionality where you can search for specified text in the box, and it will display any text it finds matching your search query in bold.

Previously I was using Lucida Console which allowed me to bold it, but then that made the bold text wider than the rest of the text. I've now tried switching to Courier New which doesn't change at all when I bold it. Is there a monospace font out there that will let me bold it properly?

Comment: I doubt it, especially if you want your program to run any all machines. Have you thought about changing the background colour, like vs does? What do you mean courier New down't change when bold? It sure does here.

Comment: Didn't think of that, I like that idea. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it, especially if you want your program to run any all machines.
What do you mean courier New doesn't change when bold? It sure does here, although not very much.

But as an alternative:  Have you thought about changing the background colour, like vs does?